# Appium inspector, no testId's on element

Tags: react-native, appium, appium-ios

I have added a test id to my button:

```
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} {...TestIdHelper(testID)}>
      <View style={[styles.iconButton, buttonStyles]}>
        <View style={styles.mainContentContainer}>
          {icon && icon}
          <Text style={[styles.iconButtonText, textStyles]}>{text}</Text>
        </View>
        {!!subText && <Text style={styles.iconButtonSubText}>{subText}</Text>}
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

When I try and inspect the element in Appium Inspector, I see nested elements with the name as the content, and no testId's. How can I add testId's?

[image]

Using